# Swift Combine making serial sequence in order

Tags: ios, swift, queue, combine

Here is the simple playground code that shows the two subscriptions in reverse order. How can I modify code so it will always print out 555? Currently it prints randomly 0 or 555 since operations are async. Please bear in mind that it is a concept, not an actual problem to solve, so putting all into one sink will not be a solution. Thanks

```
import Combine

class Foo {

    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var myProperty = 0

    var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        subject
            .sink { _ in print(self.myProperty) }
            .store(in: &bag)

        subject
            .map { _ in 555 }
            .assign(to: \.myProperty, on: self)
            .store(in: &bag)

        subject.send()
    }
}

let testClass = Foo()
```

Comment: You should amend the question to include the problem you’re trying to solve. I’ve been working with functional reactive pipelines for the better part of a decade now and not once have I needed this kind of behaviour, so I suspect this is an XY problem (you’re asking for help with X but really you need the solution to Y).

Comment: I concur with the above. A solution to your problem as written is to do the work sequentially with one publisher (eg `sink { print("1"); print("2"); print("3"); }`), so there must be more to what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for misleading, i have amended the post to show clearer challenge here

Comment: Your concept is ill-fitted to Combine as worded.   The order in which different subscribers to the same publisher receive events is undefined.  So your question is badly-formed.

If you need a temporal order to things you should reconsider how you're reacting to events.   In this example you're both storing the event and then producing a side effect (reading a member var and printing it which doesn't use the event that triggers it).   That's the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`PassthroughSubject` makes no guarantees about the order in which it will send values to its subscribers. You can't force an order, and the order could change in a future version of Combine.

One solution to store `myProperty` in its own subject, and subscribe to that subject to get the +555 values:

```
import Combine

class Foo {
    
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    private var _myProperty = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)
    var myProperty: Int { _myProperty.value }
    
    var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        _myProperty
            .sink { _ in print(self.myProperty) }
            .store(in: &bag)
        
        subject
            .map { _ in 555 }
            .assign(to: \.value, on: _myProperty)
            .store(in: &bag)
        
        subject.send()
    }
}

let testClass = Foo()
```